# C++ storing derived classes in a single vector with the derived classes not containg redifined methods

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, derived-class, base-class

I have a program with a rather complex inheritance structure, so I won't use it to show my problem but the following structure which uses bad style to keep things simple:

```
class A {
public:
    int va1;
    int va2;
    string va3;

    virtual void fa1(int x1, string x2) {
        // method body
    }

    int fa2 (bool y1, double y2) {
        // method body
    }

    A() {

    }

    virtual ~A() {

    }
};

class B :
    public A
{
public:
    bool ab1;
    double ab2;
    long double ab3;

    bool fb1(double x1) {
        //method body
    }

    long double fb2() {
        //method body
    }

    B(int z1) {
        ab2 = z1;
    }

    virtual ~B() {

    }
};

class C :
    public A
{
public:
    int ac1;

    long double fc1() {
              //method body
    }

    virtual void fa1(int x1, string x2) {
        // method body
    }

    C() {

    }

    virtual ~C() {

    }
};
```

As you can see, both B and C mostly consist of completely new variables and methods and not redefined ones from A.
As a result, using A-pointers combined with virtual methods won't work.

Until now, I have always used separate vectors or arrays for derived classes as I seldomly write programs mostly consisting of derived classes which only redefine the base classes' methods.

I know that I cannot simply create a vector of As and put in Bs and Cs without losing information.

My question is, is it possible to store As, Bs and Cs in a single vector in form of pointers or whatever and still access all methods and variables not present in A?

If it does not work with vectors, are there alternatives (arrays maybe)?

The code can contain modern C++ (standards, std::string instead of char*, etc.) as there is no need for compatibility with C or traditional C++.

Comment: You could always store everything as `A*`'s and then try a [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) to the desired derived type.  If the cast fails fails then you know you can't call the function.

Comment: Why _using A-pointers combined with virtual methods won't work_? Also, what information will you lose in _simply create a vector of As and put in Bs and Cs_?

Comment: [OT] Since when has using `std::string` become "*modern C++*"?!

Comment: Virtual functions work well if you have a class Base with virtual void example(int x) {} and a Derived class with virtual void example(int x) {}. How to solve this, I know on my own. But what about if I want to access int notInBase(double x) {}? With not having any method called like that in Base, there is now way (at least to my knowledge) to access the method (from Derived) using virtual.

Comment: "[OT] Since when has using std::string become "modern C++"?!" I still see most C++ programmers using or recommending char* or char[] instead of string, even when not working with the WindowsAPI or other legacy code. But maybe I know the wrong people and visit some not average sites.  But that's not of importance. I just wanted to ensure that I don't have a problem with new C++ standards and non-C compatible habits as it won't break my program.

Comment: @Amit, he would suffer from **[slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)** if he would put the objects directly in the vector

Comment: @Christophe - I thought he was using pointers. He's actually discussing that in the question, but after re-reading I see you're right, initially he describes using a vector of objects.

Comment: Based on my gut feeling the fact that you have unique functions in B and C either means using A as a base class is a bad design decision, or the requirement to put B and C in the same container is a bad design decision. Can you describe the business problem these classes are solving?

Comment: The actual program works like that: The Base class contains functions and variables needed by ALL derived classes. So it makes sense to use inheritance to avoid unnecessary code duplication and the trouble which is connected with it. Some derived classes will change methods of base classes. Some more some fewer. Putting all derived classes in a vector is just an idea of mine, nothing is decided yet. I just wanted to know if it is possible and if yes, is it more trouble than it is actually worth.

Comment: And the above example is rather bad, I admit. The real program does change much more methods of the base classes. However, that doesn't change the fact that derived classes still introduce new methods, playing an important role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a vector of pointers or better, a vector of **[`shared_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/)** this way:

```
vector<shared_ptr<A>> v;        // vector of shared ponters to A
v.push_back(make_shared<A>());
v.push_back(make_shared<B>(2));
v.push_back(make_shared<C>());

shared_ptr<A> pa = v[1];       // this one is a B but in real life we would'nt know
                               // I can use all the A methods without question
shared_ptr<B> pb = dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(pa);   // attempt to cast it to a B
if (pb) {                     // if casting succeded
    pb->fb2();                       // I call the B method 
} else cout << "Not a B"<<endl; // if not, I know that it's an A but not a B
```

The principle is that you store in the vector (shared) pointers to A.  So you can allways access its `A::` members.

As your base class is polymorphic (i.e. it has at least one virtual function), the `dynamic_cast` (**[`dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/dynamic_pointer_cast/)** in the case of a `shared_ptr`) can be used to try to cast the pointer to the pointer of a derived class (for example B).  If the casting succeeds (non null pointer), you know then that you can access to the `B::` members.

The use of shared_ptr vs. raw pointers, facilitates memory management:  if an object is no longer used, it's deleted automatically.

Here an **[online demo](http://ideone.com/i1yRJi)**.

Comment: Would you say that using vectors like that is a good idea or is it in most cases, more trouble than it is actually worth? In my program, for example, storing the different derived classes in their own vectors is definitely a possibility, provided I add some switches, if statements, etc.

Comment: @Willi  I've added a link to an online demo. Not knowing what your programme does, it's difficult to give an objective answer, but in general using vector like this is a very good idea. You can easily add new derived classes  later on. May be you have also a look at the visitor design pattern.